# Toolbar is not being scrolled

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-nestedscrollview

After applying NestedScrollView to activity, toolbar is not being scrolled with the content. I have tried many scroll options and flags. Height and width parameters are not written here.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="fill_vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:overScrollMode="always"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="a.fruitsbook.ScrollingActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling"
        android:overScrollMode="always">

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: why are you using NestedScrollView ?  just put your RecyclerView inside parentLayout at bottom.

Comment: I am making it like whatsapp profile view

Comment: Learn this you will get all answers of your question ,this is very usefull material demo :https://github.com/bsuhas/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop

Answer (score 0):

Remove NestedScrollView and

add  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in recyclerView.